# Limit re-rendering of page through two-way binding

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm writing an editor for the blog-posts on my homepage.

I'm using Ember's textarea-helper to bind an attribute of my model to the editor. In this textarea I type a post in markdown. Below will the output be automatically rendered (like the Stackoverflow-editor does).

My markdown also contains media-embeds from pages like YouTube or Soundcloud which makes the re-rendering very slow.

How can I limit the re-rendering of the page to like only once every five seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Ember.run.throttle`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_throttle) to avoid updating render markup too often.

Example (see also [JsBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/danip/1/)):

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  markdown: 'this is markdown',
  rendered: '',

  markdownChanged: function() {
    Ember.run.throttle(this, this.renderOutput, 5000);
  }.observes('markdown').on('init'),

  renderOutput: function(){
    this.set('rendered', 'I RENDERED THIS: ' + this.get('markdown'));
  }
});
```